# Cannot log in with Stack Exchange credentials on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Please add in the ability to easily log in with Stack Exchange credentials to the iOS app. You currently have to manually enter the URL https://stackexchange.com/ as other non-listed OpenID, rather than having a native Stack Exchange login method.

Comment: iOS app? I didn't even know there was one! (Not that I have any iOS devices, anyway! ;)

Comment: Yep there is :-) and I figured out how to log in @andrew

Comment: If you don't mind, I changed this over to a feature-request since it really should be in the application. Feel free to revert if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks @KasraRahjerdi I removed my unrelated answer as well

Comment: Please add this to the first page rather than burying it on another Open ID page.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi you work on both apps? ;)

Comment: @Shadow I'm actually now the tech lead for the entire mobile team, but all of us have our hands in at least knowledge of the other apps issues.

Comment: Congrats @KasraRahjerdi, that's good to hear!

Answer (score 6):

This feature has been implemented and will be available in version **0.1.18**

[image]